# Hardware Clock (RTC) Stuck / Will Not Increment

Tags: hardware, bios, time, realtime, clock-synchronization

After we rebooted one of our servers (RHEL), we noticed that it would hang when entering GRUB.  The problem was the countdown in GRUB (Booting in 5... 4......) was not counting down, and was stuck at 5.  At the same time, we noticed that when shutting down, the system time would fail to sync with the hardware clock.  Opening the BIOS settings revealed that the clock was stuck at 6:20:11 Oct 19 2013.  The clock does not count up, and is simply stuck at this time.  We can manually change the time and save it (it persists), but it still does not count upward.  Does anyone know how we can go about diagnosing / fixing this?

Comment: Perhaps boot up a live cd of some sort and see if you're able to set the RTC from there? If not, sounds like a (very odd) hardware issue.

Comment: I would try removing all power, including the CMOS battery, and resetting the CMOS. There's a chance that a full power cycle might unjam the CMOS clock.